# How to save images to mysql database using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a project in which i need to upload lots of images, but i dont know the acutal process of image uploading. I am using Hibernate 3 without Spring MVC . All pages are JSP pages. Main question is how to get image from request and save it to database. I have did parse the request and get all the parameters values which is form fields. What should i do for image file.??

Comment: it would be better if you just save the image path in database and save image file somewhere in server path. Also you mention you have a lots of images. That was is light weight. For saving images you can send multipart file from FORM or Using AJAX method. You need to send it as Multipart form data. Here is the sample , https://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-single-multiple-files

Answer (score 0):

To save an image into database, you need to define a table column as blob data type in MySQL, or equivalent binary type in others database. In Hibernate side, you can declare a byte array variable to store the image data.

Comment: i have done all these stuff. table , all setter and getters in POJO , but i dont know how to get image file from request and cast it into byte[] type variable .

Answer (score 0):

**First you need to download following jar file :-**

1) commons-fileupload-1.3.3
2) commons-fileupload-1.3.3-javadoc
3) commons-fileupload-1.3.3-sources
4) commons-fileupload-1.3.3-tests
5) commons-fileupload-1.3.3-test-sources
6) commons-io-2.5
7) commons-io-2.5-javadoc
**And hibernate jar files**
**You also have to set path of of your project to show image on web browser:-**
right click on project -> properties -> copy full location -> open web.xml

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>imghib</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param> 
   <description>Location to store uploaded file</description> 
   <param-name>file-upload</param-name> 
   <param-value>
      C:\Users\mohammed lala\mdlala\imghib\webContent\
   </param-value> 
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

index.html

```
 <html>
       <head>
          <title>File Uploading Form</title>
       </head>

       <body>
          <h3>File Upload:</h3>
          Select a file to upload: <br />
          <form action = "UploadServlet.jsp" method = "post"
             enctype = "multipart/form-data">
             <input type = "file" name = "file" size = "50" />
             <br />
             <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

UploadServlet.jsp

```
<%@page import="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"%>
    <%@page import="img.Image"%>
    <%@page import="org.hibernate.Transaction"%>
    <%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
    <%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.io.output.*" %>

    <%
        Session s=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx=s.beginTransaction();
       File file ;
       int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
       int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
       ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
       String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");

       // Verify the content type
       String contentType = request.getContentType();

       if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
          DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
          // maximum size that will be stored in memory
          factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);

          // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
          factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

          // Create a new file upload handler
          ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

          // maximum file size to be uploaded.
          upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

          try { 
             // Parse the request to get file items.
             List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

             // Process the uploaded file items
             Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

             out.println("<html>");
             out.println("<head>");
             out.println("<title>JSP File upload</title>");  
             out.println("</head>");
             out.println("<body>");

             while ( i.hasNext () ) {
                FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
                if ( !fi.isFormField () ) {
                   // Get the uploaded file parameters
                   String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                   String fileName = fi.getName();
                   boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                   long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();

                   // Write the file
                   if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ) {
                      file = new File( filePath + 
                      fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
                   } else {
                      file = new File( filePath + 
                      fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
                   }
                   fi.write( file ) ;
                   out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + 
                   fileName + "<br>");
                   Image ig=new Image();
                   ig.setFileName(fileName);
                   s.saveOrUpdate(ig);
                   tx.commit();
                   s.close();
                   response.sendRedirect("show.jsp?name="+fileName+" ");
                }
             }
             out.println("</body>");
             out.println("</html>");
          } catch(Exception ex) {
             System.out.println(ex);
          }
       } else {
          out.println("<html>");
          out.println("<head>");
          out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
          out.println("</head>");
          out.println("<body>");
          out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
          out.println("</body>");
          out.println("</html>");
       }
    %>
```

show.jsp

```
 <%
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    out.print(name);
    %>
    <img src="<%=name %>">
```

Image.java

```
package img;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="image")
    public class Image {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;
        private String fileName;
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }
    }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
              "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
              "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">scott</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
         <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>


         <mapping class="img.Image"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```